# To understand some terminology of metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

In the course of my study of metric spaces I've come across some terminology which I can't seem to understand completely.

So, assuming $X=\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{Q}\subset X$ is the set of the rational numbers, what exactly are:

- $\mathbb{Q}^\circ$
- int $\mathbb{Q}$
- $\partial\mathbb{Q}$
- $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$

Everywhere I looked, there is always a quite confusing explanation.

Comment: The interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ (the largest open set contained in $\mathbb{Q}$), the interior, the boundary (intersection of the closure with the closure of the complement) and the closure (smallest closed set containing $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: Maybe it would be more helpful if you could quote one of the explanations you found, and point out exactly where you are confused.  Otherwise you are just going to get more explanations, with no guarantee that they will be any less confusing to you than the ones you've already seen.  That is not very efficient for anybody.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the first two denote interior, the third boundary, and the fourth closure.

The *interior* of a set is the largest open set included in it. Equivalently, it is the union of all open sets included in it: $$\operatorname{int} S\equiv\bigcup\{U\,|\,U\text{ is open and }U\subseteq S\}.$$

Analogously, the *closure* of a set is the smallest closed set that includes it. Equivalently, it is the intersection of all closed sets including it: $$\overline S\equiv\bigcap\{C\,|\,C\text{ is closed and }S\subseteq C\}.$$

The *boundary* of a set is simply the set of points in the closure but not in the interior: $$\partial S\equiv \overline S\setminus\operatorname{int} S.$$

---

In the case of the rationals, one has that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{int}\mathbb Q=&\,\varnothing,\\
\overline{\mathbb Q}=&\,\mathbb R,\\
\partial{\mathbb Q}=&\,\mathbb R.
\end{align*}

Why? Note that every non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R$ contains a non-empty open interval and every non-empty interval, in turn, contains irrational numbers. Hence, $\mathbb Q$ cannot have any non-empty open set as its subset, so the largest open set included in it is the empty set.

On the other hand, if $C\subseteq\mathbb R$ is a closed set containing $\mathbb Q$, then $C$ must contain all irrationals, too, because every irrational is a limit of some sequence of rational numbers and the set $C$ is closed. Hence, it must be the case that $C=\mathbb R$. It follows that the smallest closed set containing $\mathbb Q$ is, in fact, $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

Int $\mathbb{Q} = \emptyset$, since, if you have an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, no matter how you choose an $r>0$, the x-centered ball($B(x,r)$), with $r$ radius will always contain an irrational number, therefore it is not an internal point. Since our $x$ was arbitrary, the set of interal points must be empty. $\rightarrow Int \mathbb{Q} = \emptyset$

Let us discuss $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ next. $\bar{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{Q'}$. Let us have an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$, no matter how you choose an $r>0$, the x-centered ball($B(x,r)$), with $r$ radius will always contain a rational number, therefore, every $x$ will be element of $\mathbb{Q'}$, so $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}= \mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{Q'}= \mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$. For that, we tend to say, that rational numbers are dense.

$\partial\mathbb{Q}=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ \ $Int(\mathbb{Q})$. Since we discussed, that $Int(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$, that will be $\mathbb{R}$ too.

By the way, $\mathbb{Q}^\circ$ and int $\mathbb{Q}$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

1. $\Bbb{Q}° = \operatorname{int}(\Bbb{Q})$

In general, given a metric space $X$ we have that $x$ is an **interior** point of $X$ if there exist an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset X$. The set $\operatorname{int}(X)$ consist of all of the interior points of $X$.

In our case we want to find $\operatorname{int}(\mathbb{Q})$. Let's see that $\operatorname{int}(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset $. Suppose its not, so there exist $x \in \operatorname{int}(\mathbb{Q})$ but what does this mean? Well, that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset \Bbb{Q}$ but, we know that between any two real numbers there exist an irrational number between them, (since the irrationals are dense in $\Bbb{R}$) so, we know that there must be an irrational $y \in (x,x+\epsilon)$ which contradicts the fact that $B(x,\epsilon)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset \Bbb{Q}$ So $\operatorname{int}(\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$

2. $\operatorname{cl}(\mathbb{Q})=\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$

The closure of a set $X$ is the union between $X$ and its accumulation points, that is $\operatorname{cl}(X)=X \cup X'$ where $X'$ is the set of accumulation points. So, what is an accumulation point? Well, $x$ is said to be an acummulation point of $X$ if for every $\epsilon >0$, $B(x,\epsilon) \cap X \neq \emptyset$. And therefore $X'$ consist of all the acumulation points of $X$

Now in our case we have $\Bbb{Q}$ and we want to find out $\Bbb{Q}'$. Lets see that $\Bbb{Q}'= \mathbb{R}$. Take $x \in \Bbb{R}$, we want to see that $x \in \Bbb{Q}'$ (the other inclusion is trivial). Ok since $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ we have that for any $\epsilon >0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap \Bbb{Q} \neq \emptyset$ and therefore $x \in \Bbb{Q}'$, concluding that $\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb{Q})=\Bbb{Q} \cup \Bbb{Q}'=\Bbb{R}$.

3. Finally, $\partial(X)=\operatorname{cl}(X)-\operatorname{int}(X)$. So in our case, $\partial(\Bbb{Q})=\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb{Q})-\operatorname{int}(\Bbb{Q})=\Bbb{R}-\emptyset = \Bbb{R}$